# rospy.wait_for_message does not get the message even though new messages are being published

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running a script where I use the rospy.wait_for_message in a while loop to wait for a message of a topic, that is publishing at certain event.

On the first event the while loop runs as expected, sometimes even on the second. I can see by running `rostopic echo /event_topic` that the messages are being published after the code stopped inside the while loop at the instruction `rospy.wait_for_message("/event_topic", Bool, timeout=None)`, but the instruction is never executed. The program just stays at this line, waiting for messages, that are being published.

When I reset the script the first one or two events are again processed as expected and that the process halts. I cannot find any errors nor warnings printed in the terminal.

This is my script:

```
import rospy
import rospkg
from std_msgs.msg import Bool
from std_msgs.msg import Float64
from std_msgs.msg import Float32MultiArray

def mynode():
    rospy.init_node('mynode')
    publisher = rospy.Publisher('/command', Float64, queue_size=1)
    
    time.sleep(.5)

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        rospy.wait_for_message("/event_topic", Bool, timeout=None)

        data = rospy.wait_for_message("/data_topic", Float32MultiArray, timeout=None)
        msg = data.data[0]

        publisher.publish(msg)
        time.sleep(.2) 
        rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        mynode()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

It also seems, that when I subscribe to the `/event_topic` by running `rostopic echo` in the terminal, the next event is being processed by the `rospy.wait_for_message`, but following, again, are not.

---

EDIT

The problem is somehow connected to the multimaster-FKIE package. I run two simulations on two ROS masters and use the multimaster-FKIE package to allow communication between them. The node shown above is supposed to read messages from topics started in one ROS master and publish messages into the topics started in the other ROS master.

When I run the node on the ROS core where the `/event_topic` was started, it works as expected. If I run the node on the ROS master where the `/data_topic` was started, the problem occurs. But I don't understand why. The topics are supposed to be shared among the ROS masters.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318535/rospy.wait_for_message-does-not-get-the-message-even-though-new-messages-are-being-published/) by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 308 on 2019-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have this:

> ```
> while not rospy.is_shutdown():
> ```

```
  [..]
  rospy.spin()
```

unless the intention to only ever run a single iteration of the `while`-loop, I don't believe that `rospy.spin()` should be there. It's essentially a non-returning statement (ie: your program will hang there indefinitely).

> When I reset the script the first one or two events are again processed as expected and that the process halts.

If by "first two events" you mean two messages, then that could be explained by the fact that you have two `rospy.wait_for_message(..)` in a row, executed *before* your script reaches the blocking `rospy.spin()`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0